# Failed upgrade disabled ssh access

Tags: shell, ssh, upgrade

While upgrading from old jessie install to stretch over ssh, I run into a problem.
The upgrade failed to install newer version of bash.
The ssh works, but the /bin/bash is missing, so any attempt to login using SSH ends with
/bin/bash: No such file or directory

As this is a remote machine with no physical access, I cannot walk to it and change default shell for the user.
And, of course, root access is disabled to login using ssh.

Is there some hack I can use to force other shell (e.g. /bin/sh) to be used by ssh?
Any ideas are welcomed.

Comment: Just spitballing here...maybe you could SCP the bash binary to where it needs to go?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/837046/482932

Comment: SCP, unfortunately, ends with the same /bin/bash missing problem :(

Comment: Tested the -t variant, but end up with the same /bin/bash no such file problem :(